# Tangents to curve intersects at the circle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Find the tangent at which the curve

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a(\sin t+\cos t) \\ a(\sin t-\cos t) \\b e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$

intersects the the circle at $xy$-plane namely

$$x^2+y^2=4a^2$$

First I found the equation of the tangent which is

$$\mathbf{r}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 + ta(\cos t-\sin t) \\
  y_1 + ta(\cos t+\sin t) \\
  z_1 - tbe^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$

after this I don't know what to do.

Comment: How can the equation of a line be exponential in the parameter?

Comment: @Aretino 
r(t)=[a(cost+sint) , a(-cost+sint) , (be^(-t))]
r'(t)=[a(cost-sint) , a(cost+sint) , -be^(-t)]
so equation of tangent by point vector formula
L= (x_1,y_1,z_1) + t[a(cost-sint) , a(cost+sint) , -be^(-t)]
  =[(x_1) + (ta(cost-sint)) , (y_1) + (ta(cost+sint)) , (z_1) - (tbe^(-t))]

I found it like this

Comment: You have TWO parameters here: one of them for a point on the curve, the other one for a point on the tangent line. You cannot use $t$ for both: I'd suggest to use $s$ for the line and rewrite your equation as $$[(x_1) + (sa(\cos t-\sin t)) , (y_1) + (sa(\cos t+\sin t)) , (z_1) - (sbe^{-t})].$$ Moreover, $x_1$, $y_1$ and $z_1$ should be expressed in terms of $t$.

Comment: I do not understand how will express them in terms of t

Comment: If possible can you give me the solution?

Comment: Point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ belongs to the curve and it is obtained by plugging into the equation of the curve the same $t$ you used for the tangent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parametric equation (with parameter $s$) of the tangent to your curve at point 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a(\sin t+\cos t) \\ a(\sin t-\cos t) \\b e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$

is

$$\mathbf{r}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a(\sin t+\cos t) + s\cdot a(\cos t-\sin t) \\
  a(\sin t-\cos t) + s\cdot a(\cos t+\sin t) \\
  be^{-t} - s\cdot be^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

A tangent intersects $xy$-plane at $z=0$, that is when $s=1$. The intersection point $P$ can then be obtained by plugging $s=1$ in the equation for the tangent:
$$\mathbf{P}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  2a\cos t \\
  2a\sin t \\
  0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
As $t$ varies along the curve, point $\mathbf{P}$ describes then a circle of center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $2a$.